# Does blender support hap codec?

Tags: video, file-format, encoding

Can anyone tell me if blender supports hap video codec?

I installed Quicktime and the hap Quicktime codec on Windows. I can set Blender's render output file format to FFmpeg Video the container to Quicktime but there is no hap codec in the codec list.

Comment: This is covered in the docs more or less: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/video_formats.html Basically, no. You can however convert it using FFMpeg outside of blender with the -vcodec option.

Comment: Thanks very much!